# How to change the graph produced by shap.summary_plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, random-forest, shap

My goal is to change the aspect of the graph produced using the shap.summary_plot in Python.

For instance, taking the example from [here](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/shap.html)

[image]

I would like to change the horizontal label from "SHAP value (impact on model output)" to a different text, and I would like to move the vertical bar "Feature Value" horizontally below the graph.

The source code of the function is [here](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/blob/master/shap/plots/_beeswarm.py), but I have been struggling in understand how to get my goals. Any comment or suggestion is highly welcomed.

UPDATE:

A recent like on this question - thanks! - reminded me that I indeed managed to find a way, which I'll share on GitHub soon.